# Removing controller path from nested route redirects to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im looking to recreate the following routes:

`localhost:3000/entertainment/this-is-my-friendly-id`

Here is my routes currently

```
  resources :categories, path: "" do
    resources :topics do
      resources :replies
    end
  end
```

Currently, im getting mixed results, and dont know enough about routes to fully customize it.

My the full route looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/categories/friendly-category-id/topics/this-is-my-friendly-id`

`categories` and `topics` is something that appears in all URLs, so I just want to drop it. I can get rid of categories easy enough, but when I do the same for `topics` (`resources :topics, path: "" do`) localhost:3000/category directs to the `index` page instead of the show.

How can i fix this?

Comment: if you look at the rails server console, do you see the params ID for topics? It would be useful if you put the `link to` to see if the problem is in the link

Comment: I edited the above for clarity.  disregarding the link_to, after I change the topics route to include `path: ""` navigating to the category route, (`localhost:3000/category_friendly_id`) will direct to the topic#index (`Processing by TopicsController#index as HTML`)

Comment: Looks like I needed to include the following, `resources :topics, path: "", :except => [:index] do`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the answer involved adding the following to the nested resource route:

```
resources :categories, path: "" do
  resources :topics, path: "", :except => [:index] do
    resources :replies
  end
end
```